# Who is this person in Naruto Ch. 678 (spoiler)?

Tags: naruto

[image]

Who is this person that the current Mizukage is marrying?

Comment: I don't think it is any known character, or that it even matters.

Comment: @JNat Maybe Mangetsu?

Comment: The hairstyle does not seem to match, and I get the impression Mangetsu is shorter than that.

Comment: I have a pretty good idea on who this might be now. Let's see if anyone else can come to the same conclusion. We can also wait for the anime too to see his hair color :)

Answer (score 5):

The character is unnamed and it really doesn't matter too.

The Fourth Mizukage's dream is to get married, and that's exactly what she got in her infinite dream.

She didn't really seem to have a preference of who to marry, but just **to** marry.

Comment: Every character in this chapter is a known character. Chances are, Mei is fantasizing about a known character too.

Comment: yeah i bet he is one of her supporter in Mizu Rebellion that died . . .